# Check noise/sound in android

Tags: android, audio, mobile, noise

I want to detect a sound/noise coming from the users voice and it will automatically stop if voice input is null.

like the app [talking tom cat](http://talkingtom.com/) where it automatically start listening when there is an sound/voice input and automatically stop when there is none.

Any help will surely be appreciated thanks! This is my project for a course

Answer (score 1):

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)  {
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
    }
});
```

Check the above method in onCreate method and on click of a button put the below code, hope it will work fine for you.

```
String text = txtWordEnglish.getText().toString();
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

tts is your TextToSpeech object, define it globally.

Any help, do let me know for this.

Comment: What is the txtWordEnglish? is that a TextView?

Comment: ya. it is a textview.